# Django REST views: return images without models

Tags: django, django-views, django-rest-framework

I am completely new to Django REST, and I have been wasting time googling for a way to accomplish something that does not seem to be excessively difficult.

I want to define a view using the Django predefined classes for views. This view should return an image (given its name), so a URL like this would return the image `example.png`:

```
http://localhost:8000/api/v1/image/example.png
```

However I do not want this image to be stored in a model (it would be stored in the server as a png file). The class `rest_framework.generics.RetrieveAPIView` seems to suit my needs, as I can set permissions and authentication classes to restrict the access to the images, but I cannot figure out how to set the `queryset` if I do not have a model with my images.

Any ideas on this? Thanks and forgive my ignorance.

Comment: What has DRF got to do with this at all? It sounds like you are retrieving an image from the server

Comment: just serve it with nginx, why you need django view for that purpose?

Comment: I have other views using DRF, and I need to set permissions and authentication classes (using JWT) to that view. I think that DRF does this nicely. Would you suggest to use a simple Django view? Is it possible to restrict access to users who do not own images in such case?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask
https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Check this page http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions/. You can use permission per view and return image from view using `content/image`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand well, you want to check permissions before allowing access to an image.

I do not think [Generic Views](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/) is the good path for you as you are not tied to a db model:

> The generic views provided by REST framework allow you to quickly
>   build API views that map closely to your database models.

A better path could be [Class Based Views](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/views/), as suggested by [Ivan Semochkin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44280387/django-rest-views-return-images-without-models#comment75567967_44280387), something like:

```
class GetMyImage(APIView):
    authentication_classes = (...,)
    permission_classes = (...,)

    def get(self, request, format=None):
        with open('file path...') as fh:
            return HttpResponse(fh.read(), content_type='content/image')
```

Of course do not forget your urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^image/example.png$', views.GetMyImage.as_view()),
]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `HttpResponse` to return simple json data. Please override `get` method in your view class.

```
import json

from django.http import HttpResponse

response_data = {}
response_data['image'] = 'http://localhost:8000/api/v1/image/example.png'

return HttpResponse(json.dumps(response_data), content_type="application/json")
```

Answer (score 0):

Django will store all your media files where you have specified your root media folder to be. It will also serve them from the specified root media url.

In your settings add;

```
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media/') 
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

Images files will be then available at 'http://localhost:8000/media/' if in your root configuration urls you add:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^api/v1/', include('api.urls', namespace='api')),
]+static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Remember to import your configuration settings and the static method:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
```